# Out-file not worked correctly

Tags: powershell

I need send ping to multiple hosts and write it to .txt files. When I run script it is worked. Script created pinged.txt and not_pinged.txt file but not add pinged and not_pinged users to this files.

```
$ServerName = Get-Content -Path 'C:\ps\user.txt' 

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) 
{

    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet) 
    {
        Write-Host "$Server" -ForegroundColor Green | out-file "C:\ps\pinged.txt" -Append
    }
    else        
    {
        Write-Host "$Server" -ForegroundColor Red | out-file "C:\ps\not_pinged.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't understand your Question. [*blush*] would you please add what you want from the code ... and how it is not working as needed?

Comment: Write host can’t be piped to out-file.

Comment: In the script I sent ping to user in list and I need add pinged and not pinged usernames writed two files.

Comment: [Avoid Write-Host](https://powershell-guru.com/powershell-best-practice-3-avoid-write-host/). and http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/